# Visual Studio Code command for "repeat last command"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a command which does "repeat last command"? If not, how can I set up such a thing?

Basically what I want is to press some shortcut, and for it to repeat whatever the last command was, so I don't have to find it again in the menu or the <kbd>ctrl-shift-p</kbd> box.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is one. Here's the [default keybidings for windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) (other OS's are easy to find). In Visual Studio, we have Undo and Redo (Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-Y). There's something undo related for multi-cursor but no sign of Redo, which is what we'd expect it to be called for VS/VS code familiarity reasons.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's unfortunate. It would have been useful.

Comment: Are you interested in a macro solution?  And is your "last command" always found in the  command palette - you mention finding it in the menu - do you have an example of command in a menu not in the palette?  I am just asking because the macro is straightforward for the command palette commands.

Comment: @Mark a macro that can be bound to some shortcut? For something in the ctrl-p box - sounds like a good alternative. I added an issue to the repo, looks like they'll add this at some point.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but for those interested in only repeating the **last terminal command**; there is this simple [Re-run Last Command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cameron.rerun-last-command) available. Shortkey is configurable with that.

Comment: @Julien See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336497/make-a-keybinding-to-run-previous-or-last-shell-commands No need for an extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can press `Ctrl + Shift + P`, then `Enter` it also repeat the lastest command.

Take a look:

[image]

Comment: Just a note: If you have the focus on `main.py` and you run `Run Python File in Terminal` it executes `main.py`. But there was an error in `error.py`. You go and fix it (moved focus to `error.py`). Now you want to run it again and obviously it will execute `error.py`

Comment: Doesn't work if the command has an argument you need to provide.

Comment: You can press `F1` then `Enter`

Answer (score 8):

If you are specifically looking to rerun the last shell command, see [Make a keybinding to run previous or last shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336497/make-a-keybinding-to-run-previous-or-last-shell-commands)

---

Older answer (see above)

So this is a little funky because for the `workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem` command to work, the command palette must be open.  So it will flash open briefly whenever you use the macro keybinding.

Using the [macrosRe extension:](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=l7ssha.macrosRe)

```
"macros": {
    
  "rerunCommand": [
    "workbench.action.showCommands",
    "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem"
      
  ]
}
```

I assume you have   `"workbench.commandPalette.history": 50,` set to at least one so that the most recently used command is at the top of the command palette.  [I think that setting always puts the last command at the top and selects it.]

And then some keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+;",
    "command": "macros.rerunCommand"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac simple Ctrl-P repeats the last command on the terminal. Looks like they updated it!

Answer (score 1):

> If you are specifically looking to rerun the last shell command, see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, with [Make a keybinding to run previous or last shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55336498/6309)

Actually, with VSCode 1.70 (July 2022), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> is no longer limited to running the *last* command.

See [issue 154306](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154306) "Add context key for run recent command open"

> The views picker (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>) lets you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> again to go down the list:
>
> ```json
> { "key": "ctrl+q", 
>    "command": >"workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInViewPicker",
>    "when": "inQuickOpen && inViewsPicker" 
> },
> ```
>
> This is behavior we could copy in the **`run recent command`** to make it act even more like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> in the shell

This is implemented in [PR 154552](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154552) and released in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

You now have the possibility to associate to your key shortcut a

```
"when": "InTerminalRunCommandPicker"
```

---

And with VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022):

> ### [allow recent commands to be pinned](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/158037)
>
> From [issue 154388](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154388): Allow pinning of commands in Run recent command quickpick

From

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35271042/178366598-9a6e520b-1e7c-4e74-ad7b-a08d4907493d.png]

To:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35271042/178366684-1f77ce44-ef8f-433d-b986-d3fe9b6065eb.png]

This is released in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

---

VSCode 1.75 (Jan. 2023) implements "Commonly Used" list in the first-time-opened Command Palette ([issue 169091](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/169091)), with [PR 171293](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/171293)

It adds the setting:

> ### `workbench.commandPalette.experimental.suggestCommands`
>
> Controls whether the command palette should have a list of commonly used commands.

Answer (score -4):

You can press Shift + Alt + Down arrow key it will repeat the latest command on windows VS code.