# Make a keybinding to run previous or last shell commands

Tags: shell, powershell, visual-studio-code

I frequently want to quickly re-run the last shell command that I used.

I know you can shift focus to the terminal, up arrow and enter but I thought there must be a better way than these three steps.

The `sendSequence` command in vscode is getting more powerful and so I looked for a way to create a keybinding that will run the last shell command quickly.

From [sendSequence documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding):

> **Send text from a keybinding**
>
> The `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` command can be used to send
>   a specific sequence of text to the terminal, including escape
>   sequences. This enables things like sending arrow keys, enter, cursor
>   moves, etc. The example below shows the sorts of things you can
>   achieve with this feature, it jumps over the word to the left of the
>   cursor (Ctrl+Left arrow) and presses backspace:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+u",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "\u001b[1;5D\u007f" }
}
```

> This feature supports variable substitution.
>
> Note that the command only works with the `\u0000` format for using
>   characters via their character code (not `\x00`).

See [terminal supports variables substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_32#_integrated-terminal):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": ". ${file}" }
}
```

For example, see [run files in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082394/run-files-in-terminal-from-vs-code/55082505#55082505):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "node '${file}'\u000D" }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With vscode v1.69 and shell integration enabled, there is now a built-in command to do this (for supported shells).

1. Eanble the setting `Terminal > Integrated > Shell Integration: Enabled`
2. Set a shortcut for the command `Terminal: Run Recent Command` from the `Keyboard Shortcuts` editor.

You should end up with a keybinding like this (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+x",         // whatever you chose as a keybinding
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runRecentCommand"
}
```

Supported shells are limited to Windows: pwsh and Linux/Mac: bash, pwsh and zsh.

> This setting applies only when terminals are created, so you will need
> to restart your terminals for it to take effect.

---

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70900927/836330 for how to see a QuickPick of recent terminal commands (in preview as of v1.64) for certain supported shells and OS's.

---

I came up with this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+x",

  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      
  "args": { "text": "\u001b[A\u000d" }
},
```

1. `\u001b` is an escape sequence to indicate the following characters have special meaning.
2. `[A` is an up arrow.  See, e.g., [xterm function keys](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands):

   ```
   Cursor Up    | CSI A
   Cursor Down  | CSI B
   Cursor Right | CSI C
   Cursor Left  | CSI D
   ```

(the "CSI" refers to `ESC` or `\u001b` or followed by a `[` and stands for "Control Sequence Introducer" (CSI  is 0x9b).)

So "CSI A" is `\u001b[A` which is equal to an up arrow which should cycle your terminal command list to the previous command.

3. `\u000d` is a return, so the command runs immediately.

Now <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> or whatever keybinding you choose will run the last shell command used, focus can be in the editor or the terminal.

For fun I put together this command:

```
"args": { "text": "\u0012watch\u001b[1;5C" }
```

That will send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to the terminal which searches previous commands.

Then it will search for "`watch`", and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> to go to the end of "`watch`" where you could modify arguments if need be.

Or skip the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> part (`\u001b[1;5C`) and do a return (`\u000d`) to run the command that was found anywhere in your history.  Obviously, you will need a unique search term for that to work.

[Tested in powershell and git bash.  Not tested elsewhere.]

Comment: cool answer, but I really hope the developers make it easier than this to run previous shell command.