# Terminal up arrow - not repeating last command

Tags: visual-studio-code

Until recently when I was in terminal and pressed arrow up, it would automatically insert my last typed command in the terminal.
Now, up arrow doesn't do anything, just an annoying sound.

I use vscode on Windows 10 platform.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  And did you recently change it?

Comment: It is easy to get that functionality another way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336497/make-a-keybinding-to-run-previous-or-last-shell-commands  But that doesn't explain what changed in your case.  But the linked answer is nice because you don't have to switch focus to the terminal first.  (Not tested in ALL shells.)