# VS Code: How to Switch Between Code and Terminal *Without* Focusing the Dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are already several questions about "how do I switch back and forth between code and the terminal in VS Code", and the (correct) answer to all of them is:

```
ctrl + `
```

But there's a problem with that answer.  I very often switch to the terminal and hit `up + ENTER` to run the previous command.  However, when I do so too quickly, VS Code focuses me not on the terminal, but on the terminal-switching-dropdown in the upper right corner.

As a result, I wind up changing terminals (because the `up + ENTER` goes into the dropdown and not the terminal itself) ... when I just want to focus the existing terminal and type there.

Is there any way to make VS code *not* focus on that dropdown?  Or even just to remove it entirely?

Comment: Tried to do this on my system (version 1.43.1, running on Ubuntu) but does not happen for me at all, however fast I try to do `ctrl + \` + up`. I assume you already checked that this key sequence has not been bound to anything in your system?

Comment: I checked and `ctrl + \` + up` and don't have it mapped.  I also just tried doing it now, and ... it doesn't do it for me ATM either.   Under some conditions (maybe when the editor is busy doing other things?) it focuses the dropdown instead of the terminal itself, but I'm not sure exactly what those conditions are (I always hit them by accident).

Comment: yeah, possibly. I used a backslash before the tilde to format it.

Comment: Thanks (fixed my comment).  I'll try to suss out those conditions and report back, but maybe someone else familiar with this issue will respond in the meantime.

Comment: You don't need to switch focus to the terminal to re-run your last command.  You can do it from anywhere with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336497/make-a-keybinding-to-run-previous-or-last-shell-commands  focus would stay in your editor and run the last command.  If you want something else, that answer could probably be modified to re-run the last command and then switch focus to the terminal.

Comment: It actually seems like just pressing `CTRL +\`` (without even pressing "up") opens up a new bash shell instead of going into the existing terminal ... but I have yet to determine **why** it only rarely does that, but usually sends me into the normal (existing) terminal.  Why VS Code, why?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem wasn't the `up` key, it was the `SHIFT` key.  In VS Code `CTRL + tilde` sends you to the terminal, but `` CTRL + SHIFT + ` `` instead opens a new terminal session.

(As a side note, I could use the "code" tag to express that second tilde, but Stack Overflow botches both tildes and the "code" tag when I try to format just "CTRL + tilde".)

The shift key on my keyboard sticks sometimes, and it was making this happen without me realizing it (and I mistakenly attributed it to the `up` key since I press both together).

Thanks to everyone who helped me narrow the problem down in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

- `CRTL + 1` = focus on editor while your focus on terminal
- `` CRTL + ` `` = focus on terminal while your focus on editor