# Repeated terminal command in VSCode

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a large angular / .NET Core project and have to type e.g. `dotnet run /path/to/subproject` in the terminal often.

Can I use VSCode to store/manage these common commands? I've been through the vscode docs on `launch.json` and `tasks.json` but cannot find a good answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a couple of options.

(1) Set up a command to just rerun the last command - see [Make a keybinding to run previous or last shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336497/make-a-keybinding-to-run-previous-or-last-shell-commands)

```
{
  "key": "alt+x",          // choose your keybinding    
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",    
  "args": { "text": "\u001b[A\u000d" }
},
```

or (2)  just put your frequently-used command into a keybinding ala:

```
{
  "key": "alt+x",          // choose your keybinding    
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",    
  "args": { "text": "dotnet run /path/to/subproject\u000d" },
  //  "when": "terminalFocus"
},
```

The `\u000d` is a `return` so the command runs immediately.  I find it easiest to not have the `when` clause so I can run it from anywhere - editorFocus or terminalFocus, etc.

These go into your `keybindings.json`.

You can use variables where you have `/path/to/subproject`.  See [task - variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution) and [available variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables) which may help with your path.

Comment: I was actually hoping for something a little more concrete, something that could be checked into source control and not interfere with my and others' keybindings.