# VSCode Terminal command names for Up/Down Arrow hotkeys?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10

I want to change the hotkeys for cycling recent commands when terminal has focus but I cant find the command names I need.
I looked around in .Json file but did not find the two commands.

Something like below is what I have in mind, Only that I am missing command name.

```
{ "key": "F1", "command": ".....", "when": "terminalFocus"},
```

Am on Win10
Thank you.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55336498/836330 for more info.

Comment: Also, you won't find vscode commands for those operations because those are shell commands (and may vary by shell).  But as the links show you can send an uparrow or downarrow to the terminal and achieve the same thing.

Comment: Sorry about that, I plan to improve on my searching skills. Thank you for link